# Probability question regarding arrangements

Tags: probability

Can someone please help with this question:
Rewa and Stefan are both members of the Student Council. The Student Council comprises ten 
members. When the Student Council is introduced to the school at an assembly, the Student Council members sit in a row on stage. The seats are allocated at random. 
What is the probability that Rewa will be seated on the extreme left of the row, and Stefan will be seated on the extreme right of the row at the school assembly?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  Could you explain exactly where you are having difficulty with this problem?  That makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I am not sure even how to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
& \Pr(\text{Rewa on left and Stefan on right}) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(\text{Rewa on left})\cdot\Pr(\text{Stefan on right}\mid \text{Rewa on right}) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac 1 9
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

There are $10!$ possible ways of arranging the ten council members in a row. If we fix either end to be Rewa and Stefan, there are 8! ways of arranging the 8 inner students. Since each arrangement is equally likely (by the assumption that seats are assigned randomly), the probability is $8!/10! = 1/90$.

Comment: Thanks guys really helped i get how to do it now Michael ur answer is much more easier to understand :)